# C load from file to struct specificators

Tags: c, file, struct

I am trying to load from a file to a specific fields in a struct. I am having huge problems with specificators. Should I load sign by sign or just the whole string? Can anybody help with my specificators? Struct values contains bits : 5 , 5 and 11 and it should be like this. I should disgard first number `1. , 2. , 3.`

Edit. What if is a binary file?

Input file :

```
1. John Snow, 05/06/1996 (0x00000000001f3cc1)⏎
2. Ethan Downey Jr., 14/02/1945 (0x00000000001e644e)⏎
...
10. ...
```

```
union unione{
    unsigned long value;
    struct {
        unsigned char d : 5;
        unsigned char m : 5;
        unsigned short int y : 11;
    }bit;
};

struct structure {
    char name[21];
    union unione bity;
    char surname[31];
};

int readfile(const char* filename, struct structure* buffer, int size){
    if (!fname || !buffer || size < 1) return 1;

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!f) return 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fscanf(f, "%*d. %s %s, %d/%d/%d (%x)", (*(buffer+i)).name, (*(buffer+i)).surname, (*(buffer+i)).bity.bit.d,
               (*(buffer+i)).bity.bit.m, (*(buffer+i)).bity.bit.y, (*(buffer+i)).bity.value);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct structure data[10];
    readfile("birthdays.bin", data, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are more problems with this approach.

The first problem is the file and the fscanf: fscanf reads in a predefined format, but you have names that have 2 part and names that have 3 parts, like "John Snow" and "Ethan Downey Jr.". This is very problematic to read, I would advice you to use only 2 part name, and put some special character between parts that count as one, so that you can separate them later. Like this "Ethan Downey_Jr.". You read the name as two strings, then replace the '_' with ' '.

Another thing that is not clear to me, is that union. It has a "value" and that strucure containing day, month and year. Now, union takes up the memory place of its largest member, meaning that these fields, the value and the struct are take up the same memory (long being the larger). So it does not really make sense to reak the day, month and year into the union, the overwrite them with the value. If the "day, month, year" struct and the "value" have the same value, then it is redundancy in the text file, which is again, not preferred.

So my suggestions: think this trough, are "value" and "struct bit" the same? Maybe use struct instead of union? If they are the same, then there is redundancy in the text file, do you need that?

But anyway, one solution would be:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

union unione {
    unsigned long value;
    struct {
        unsigned char d : 5;
        unsigned char m : 5;
        unsigned short int y : 11;
    }bit;
};

struct structure {
    char name[21];
    union unione bity;
    char surname[31];
};

int readfile(const char* filename, struct structure* buffer, int size) {
    if (!filename || !buffer || size < 1) return 1;

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!f) return 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int day, month, year, value;
        memset(buffer[i].name, 0, 21);
        memset(buffer[i].surname, 0, 31);
        buffer[i].bity.value = 0;
        fscanf(f, "%*d. %s %[^,], %d/%d/%d (%x)", buffer[i].name, buffer[i].surname, &day, &month, &year, &value);
        buffer[i].bity.bit.d = day;
        buffer[i].bity.bit.m = month;
        buffer[i].bity.bit.y = year;
        //buffer[i].bity.value = value;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct structure data[10];
    readfile("birthdays.txt", data, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%s %s, %d/%d/%d (%x)\n", data[i].name, data[i].surname, data[i].bity.bit.d,
            data[i].bity.bit.m, data[i].bity.bit.y, data[i].bity.value);
    }
}
```

Note that here I was working with 2 part names, like "Ethan Downey_Jr.", but did not replace '_' with ' '. But that is not hard to achieve.

Have fun and good luck, I hope this helped.

Comment: Also, you see that I did a memset on the strings before filling them. This is necessary, because printf will print until it reaches a '\0' character. So if the string is filled with '\0' before reading into it, there will be 0s after the names and not some junk.

Comment: What if the file is actually.. binary?

Comment: Well I am not sure that fscanf works with binary files. I don't really see why a file containing text would be binary, but in the worst case scenario you could read the file one byte at a time. Of course only if you are using 1 byte character encoding, so no fancy characters.